# How do I copy a file with a variable name into a different folder?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I am trying to copy a file from a folder and paste it to another. Hence, the function FileCopy seemed a great solution. However, the file I want to copy will change name every day, therefore I called it value3 in my code and the name follows a cell in my workbook.

However, I have an error (File not found, error 53), at the last line of the code :

```
FileCopy myFPName, myNewDir & value3
```

```
Sub copytxtfileinfolder()

    Dim myFPName As String
    Dim myNewDir As String
    Dim value3 As String
    value3 = Worksheets("Offset Helper Sheet").Range("B29").Value
'   Full name and path of original file
    myFPName = "G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Pepper Automation\Pepper sync\" & " value3"
'   Name of new directory to copy to
    myNewDir = "G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Pepper Automation\Payments Holidays\Payment Holidays txt\"
'   Copy file to new directory with same name
    FileCopy myFPName, myNewDir & value3

End Sub
```

Comment: That error means that your `MyFPName` doesn't have a real path to an existing file, have you checked the value of `MyFPName` when the error pops?

Comment: `value3` is a variable so it shouldn't be enclosed in quotes `"`.

Comment: I have delete the quotes for value 3, and I checked the value of myFPName and it shows the correct path.

Comment: I still get the same error. myFName looks like this now: myFPName = "G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Pepper Automation\Pepper sync\value3"

Comment: Also, the statement you posted above is incorrect. `value3` should not be in the path but the actual file name (with extension).

Comment: value3 does not contain the file extension, it's txt file therefore myFPName = "G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Pepper Automation\Pepper sync\value3.txt" right ?

Comment: `value3` is a variable that holds the value of `Worksheets("Offset Helper Sheet").Range("B29").Value`. This should be a filename with extension.

Comment: it does not work either

Comment: Can you post the value of `Worksheets("Offset Helper Sheet").Range("B29").Value`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies with this line:

```
myFPName = "G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Pepper Automation\Pepper sync\" & " value3"
```

Assuming value3 holds something like File.txt, there are no parentheses needed. If you enclose it with parentheses, the file it is looking for is `G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Pepper Automation\Pepper sync\value3` *(initial space removed automatically by Excel; instead value of value3 it looks for literrally a file named value3)* (edited)

Correction:

```
myFPName = "G:\Shared drives\Reporting\Power BI Source Files- DO NOT TOUCH\Pepper Automation\Pepper sync\" & value3
```

Comment: Are you saying Excel will append `.xlsx` if you try to copy a file with no extension?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense, however I still get the file not found error at the last line of the code. value3 gives me the correct name for my file, I do not get it

Comment: @KostasK. I assumed so as I sometimes get the similar error on opening the file by VBA code (where it does add .xlsx) but you're right, it doesn't add extension when copying :) editing the answer

Comment: @AntoineBonin could you paste the exact content of  ` Worksheets("Offset Helper Sheet").Range("B29").Value ` as Kostas requested? There might be some white characters that make the filename seen not the same as filename recognizable by Excel. Was it typed manually or copied from somewhere?

Comment: oh, and I have another guess what could go wrong. You're sure you have folder "Shared drives" on G:\ ? Is the path directly copied?

Comment: @annanananan My file name is 20200528_PaymentHolidays, which is also the value in cell B29. This is the formula in the cell : =TEXT(Assumptions!B1-1,"yyymmdd")&"_PaymentHolidays"

Comment: yes for the drive it's the correct path, I have copy-pasted it in the vba

Comment: I tried to hardcode the file name in the code but I still get a file not found error, which shows that the problem does not come from the variable but from the lookup of the file

Comment: Where is the extension of the file? It should be in the filename as well, for example `=TEXT(Assumptions!B1-1,"yyymmdd")&"_PaymentHolidays.txt" `